# Rust `unresolved import` when trying to import an external crate into a module not in the root directory

Tags: rust, enums, rust-diesel, derive

I'm very new to Rust, so maybe this is an obvious question, but I couldn't find anything that answered it. I can't seem to import the external crate `diesel_derive_enum` in my module sub-module `database/models.rs`. It works perfectly if I simply move the `models.rs` file to the `src/` directory. I'm guessing I'm missing something where I need to tell it to look up to the root level for the external crate?

I have a project that's structured like:

```
src
├── database
│   ├── models.rs
│   ├── mod.rs
│   └── schema.rs
└── main.rs
```

#### Models.rs

```rust
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel_derive_enum;
use uuid::Uuid;

use super::schema::market_trade_goods;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, diesel_derive_enum::DbEnum)] // <- error is here
#[ExistingTypePath = "crate::schema::sql_types::SupplyType"]
pub enum SupplyType {
    Scarce,
    Limited,
    Moderate,
    Abundant,
}
// ...then more
```

#### database/mod.rs

```rust
pub mod models;
pub mod schema;
```

#### main.rs

```rust
mod database;

use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::prelude::*;
use dotenvy::dotenv;
use std::env;
use uuid::Uuid;

use crate::database::models::{SupplyType, TradeGood};
// ...then some more functions and whatnot
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways of importing things like `crate::diesel_derive_enum` or `extern crate diesel_derive_enum` (in `models.rs` and `main.rs`). Nothing seems to make a difference, but I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious.

Edit: Full error message is:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: unresolved import
 --> src/database/models.rs:8:35
  |
8 | #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, diesel_derive_enum::DbEnum)]
  |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                                   |
  |                                   unresolved import
  |                                   help: a similar path exists: `crate::database::schema`
  |
  = note: this error originates in the derive macro `diesel_derive_enum::DbEnum` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: This code should work. What is the error (full error, from `cargo check`)?

Comment: I've just edited the post to include the full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derive macro itself is resolved correctly, but its expansion includes `crate::schema::sql_types::SupplyType`. The problem is, `schema` is not directly under the crate root - it is under `database`. So change it to:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, diesel_derive_enum::DbEnum)] // <- error is here
#[ExistingTypePath = "crate::database::schema::sql_types::SupplyType"]
pub enum SupplyType {
    Scarce,
    Limited,
    Moderate,
    Abundant,
}
```

Comment: You're a hero, that totally worked. I pretty much just copy-pasted `ExistingTypePath` so I'll have to do some more reading up on what that does.  Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to open an issue for this error message in the `diesel_derive_enum` github repository. I think it should be possible for them to improve this error message so that it points at least to `crate::schema::sql_types::SupplyType` by using `quote_spanned` in the right place instead of using just `quote!`